# How to consume multiple kafka message at same topic with multiple ack?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume multiple message from a topic with manual ack but ack work if all message only by ack one time.

```
@KafkaListener(
    id = "${kafka.buyers.product-sales-pricing.id}",
    topics = "${kafka.buyers.product-sales-pricing.topic}",
    groupId = "${kafka.buyers.group-id}",
    concurrency = "${kafka.buyers.concurrency}"
)
public void listen( List<String> message, Acknowledgment ack ){}
```

In above code i am getting 5 message per consume if i put following configuration in spring boot property file:

```
kafka:
  max-poll-records: 5 # Maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll()
```

but if i ack that listen then it ack all 5 message at same time.

Actually i want to ack separately for each message(means 5 message with 5 ack).

How can i do this in spring boot project?

Answer (score 3):

When using a batch listener, the entire batch is acked when `Acknowledgment.acknowledge()` is called.

I would recommend using a single record listener rather than a batch listener for this use case.

listen(String msg, Acknowledgment ack)

It's not clear why you would commit offsets for only part of the batch.

If you must use a batch listener, it can still be done, but rather more complicated - you would need to get `List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>>` to get topic/partition/offset information and also add `Consumer<?, ?> consumer` to the method parameters (and remove the `Acknowledgment`; you can then call `commitOffsets()` on the consumer however you want. But you MUST call it on the listener thread - the consumer is not thread-safe.

Comment: Hi gary,

your answer and ankit question do not match. Because if we use: `public void listen( ConsumerRecords<String, String> messages, Consumer<String, String> consumer )` and `consumer.commitAsync()` or `consumer.commitSync()`, then it also Acknowledg group of message received in batch. Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @AKA yes you are right this issue still exist for me.

Comment: @Gary If i use single record listener rather than a batch listener, performance wise bot are same?

Comment: @ankit Yes, as long as you use the default `AckMode.BATCH`; if you use `AckMode.RECORD` the offset will be committed after each record. By the way, there is a [new feature in the next release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#committing-offsets) where you can ack part of the batch and the unprocessed records are redlivered.

Comment: @AKA It's better to leave the commits to the container by calling `ack.acknowledge()` with the `AckMode` to MANUAL or MANUAL_IMMEDIATE. If you commit directly on the `Consumer` you should disable container commits (AckMode.MANUAL) so the container won't commit any offsets.

Comment: @AKA : "Hi gary, your answer and ankit question do not match. " That is not correct; his/her question does not have the `Consumer` as a parameter on the listener method.